# SharePoint 2010 login page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am currently design the SharePoint 2010 internet site using Claim based authentication. Currently i have enabled Anonymous access and hide the ribbon for anonymous user.

What i am trying to do is to link create login page link in the footer like the following:

```
<div class="bFooter">
  <p>
   Website  | <a href="/_layouts/Authenticate.aspx">Login</a> | 
                Website<a href=""></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

the login page will need to authenticate using Windows Authentication. Please advise, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a look at this link...Its a good article on cusotm login form in SP2010.

http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/